# How do you implement interstitial iads into a sprite kit game in swift?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, iad, interstitial

I have looked around the internet but i can't find out how to implement interstitial iAds into my sprite kit game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following code in your viewcontroller will do it. nothing more to it. you can invoke it with an NsNotofication or delegate from within your scene.

```
func fullScreenAd() {
    if self.requestInterstitialAdPresentation() {
        println("ad loaded")
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, what code do i use in my scene to invoke it using a NSNotification?

Comment: don't worry, i worked out how to do it! thanks!

Comment: glad you figured it out @BenOneill